# Hashtable to string/JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010

Im working whit hash tables in visual studio 2010 (homework personal investigation)
i need to create a json type file whit the content of a hash table
either convert to string or directly to json should work.
Already have a hashtable whit the key,value.

```
   string hashtable_data = string.Join(",", data.Keys.Cast<object>().
   Select(x  => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

The abode code save only the key in a backward order.
can´t add the value to the string,how can i add the key and the value?

Answer (score 1):

As Dictionary inherits an `IEnumebable<T>` interface, you can use standart linq `select` as follow:

```
string hashtable_data = string.Join(",", data.Select(
    x  => "\"" + x.Key + "\":\"" +x.Value+"\""
    ).ToArray());
```

However you have to be very careful about JSON grammar:

- escape `"` in key and value
- treat string values in `""` like above example
- all other object like numbers, objects treat without '""'
- 'undefined' is not a valid JSON value
- I'm sure there is more  rules

For this I would use some [JSON library](http://www.json.org/) to (de)serialize fully valid JSON.